# Python importing issue

Tags: python, import

I have a module(Executive.py) that I am trying to import into another module I am working on (ExecutiveTest.py).  The directory structure is like so:

```
src/
   common/
         python/
               Executive.py
         tests/
               ExecutiveTest.py
```

In ExecutiveTest.py, I have the following line:

```
from common.Executive import Executive
```

I get an error saying:`ImportError: No module named common.Executive`

How do I correct this import error?

Comment: Why do you say "common.Executive" when that is NOT the path to the module?

Comment: Also, see the documentation on packages: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 2):

You have to have an `__init__.py` file in the root of your package (it can be empty). Also, your module hierarchy has to reflect the directory structure, so `python` and `tests` should be part of the import as well.

Comment: which module?  Executive or ExecutiveTest?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder). it looks like you can define the path that python refers to when looking for stuff to import. Something like:

sys.path.append(  )